# Different objects when deferring with deferred.done()?

Tags: jquery

When synchronizing ajax requests, example:

```
$.when(
    $.get("/api/foo", { prm: 1 }),
    $.get("/api/bar", { prm: 2 })
).done(function (data1, data2) {
    doStuff(data1[0].Value, data2[0].Value);
});
```

I am getting result objects from the deferred $.get call, that are different to what I am getting when simply calling $.get:

```
$.get("/api/foo", { prm: 1 }, function (data) { doStuff(data.Value); });
```

Basically the information that I need is at index 0 of the objects passed to done() (and there is a "success" string at index 1 and raw data at index 2).

I would like to know when and how the result object is being altered this way and if it is safe to always look out for the data at index 0.

Comment: It's different because the done callback normally has 3 parameters, not one. In order for it to correctly represent all three, it's using an array. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: It is not safe to *"always"* look at index 0 because if there's only one request passed to `$.when`, it won't be an array, you'll just want `data.Value`.

Comment: Documentation says done() can take any number of functions or arrays of functions. I expected it to get whatever the callback of the deferred function gets.

Comment: Right, but how would you expect it to represent the returned data(remember, the returned data consists of **three** parameters, not one) when you have more than one request vs when you have one request

Comment: You are right, I did not understand this before reading Udi Cohen's anwer which explains that I omitted parameters which will be "discovered" with when().done()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to rely on the data[0] since this is how when works.
Your single get call should look like this:

```
$.get("/api/foo", { prm: 1 }, function (data, statusText, jqXHR) { doStuff(data.Value); });
```

But you chose to omit the other parameters, which is OK.
Now it is easier to understand why using jQuery.when forces you access the data[0]... because data[0] is the first parameter of the get result, data[1] is the status text and data[2] is the jqXHR.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense now, but I wouldn't have found out so easy.